# I can't order the controls

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

i make a windows where i can create a new user, but i cant order the internal controls.

Code example:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ventanaEmergente" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <%--Boton close--%>
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4>Formulario de clientes</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="form-inline" role="form">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-centered">
                    <label for="inputInsertName" class="control-label">Nombre: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputInsertName" placeholder="Ingrese su Nombre">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-centered">
                    <label for="inputInsertApellido" class="control-label">Apellido: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputInsertApellido" placeholder="Ingrese su Apellido">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Can i help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean by `internal controls`? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Into the window, sry, i need more trainer with my english.

Comment: What do you mean by "order"? Controls usually appear in the order they are declared in the html. Can't you just move them around in the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to align the controls within your BootStrap Modal window. Place all your `body` controls within `<div class="modal-body">`. Here is the link to the working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yy2Lkvkn/1/)
 Refer [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) for more details.

Here is the code

```
<div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Formulario de clientes</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-centered">
             <label for="inputInsertName" class="control-label">Nombre: </label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputInsertName" placeholder="Ingrese su Nombre">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-centered">
             <label for="inputInsertApellido" class="control-label">Apellido: </label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputInsertApellido" placeholder="Ingrese su Apellido">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
 </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
```